# What is the correct way to update an array child to parent in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

So I'm learning Vue.js, and after a bit of struggle I (somehow) got the following piece of code **working**. I know that if it works, it ain't stupid, but nevertheless I would like help on how to improve my code as I doubt whether I'm taking the right approach.

The following code allows the user to add multiple instances of the Item component by clicking the button. The input of the name field in Item is passed to a object with is inserted in an array which is sent back to the parent component.

My main problem with this approach is that the items array is shared between all instances of Item as a prop, which is unnecessary. I can't, however, come up with another solution because I only know how to share data between components by passing it as a prop and updating. I also read that props should only be updated by the parent so I'm guessing I'm also violating that rule.

Could someone teach me a better approach?

**Parent code**

```
<template>

    <div class="items">
         <div v-for="n in itemCount">
            <Item :count="n" :items="items"  />
         </div>
    </div>

    <button @click="addItem">Add item</button>

</template>

<script>
    import Item from './../components/Item'; //the child 

    export default {

        components: {
            Item
        },

        data() {
            return {
                itemCount: 1,
                items: [],
            }
        },

        methods: {
            addItem() {
                this.itemCount ++;
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

**Child**

```
<template>

    <div class="item">
        <label>Item name</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="name" @input="update(count)" />    
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {

        props: ['items','count'],

        data() {
            return {
                name: '',
            }
        },

        methods: {

            createItem(index) {
                return {
                    index: index-1,
                    name: this.name,
                }
            },

            update(index) {
                const item = this.createItem(index);
                this.$set(this.items, index-1, item);
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're justified in feeling uncomfortable with the initial implementation. Ideally, a child component should not assume anything about its parent. In this case, the child component is simply rendering a `<label>` and `<input>` for the user to enter an item name. It shouldn't know, or care, that there are multiple items. Here's one way to create such a component. It's effectively defining it's own model and simply reflecting that model to the `<input>`:

```
Vue.component('custom-item', {
  props: {
    value: String
  },
  template: `
    <div class="custom-item">
      <label>Item name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        :value="value"
        @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
      >
    </div>
  `
});
```

The parent component then simply supplies the appropriate `v-model` to the child: (Note that I've moved the `<button>` inside the root element, as a template cannot have more than one direct child element.)

```
Vue.component('custom-items', {
  data() {
    return {
      items: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      items.push({
        index: items.length,
        name: ""
      });
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div class="custom-items">
      <div v-for="item in items">
        <custom-item v-model="item.name"/>
      </div>
      <button @click="addItem">
        Add item
      </button>
    </div>
  `
});
```

That code uses the same structure for the `items` objects, but it seems unlikely that you actually need the `.index` property, in which case `items` could just be an array of strings rather than objects.

Also, unless you're doing something funky with styling, you don't actually need the `<div>` wrapper around each custom item, so you could ditch that for simplicity:

```
    <div class="custom-items">
      <custom-item
        v-for="item in items"
        v-model="item.name"
      />
      <button @click="addItem">
        Add item
      </button>
    </div>
```

There may be some typos in the above as I haven't tested it, but I think you can get the idea.

Comment: Thank you! No clue why I didn't think of updating the array on the parent. I called addItem on the parent on mounted() so I have one instance of Item already just like in my approach. 

Only issue left is that now I don't know how I can add more elements on the child component (i.e. 2 input elements, such as item first name / last name)  as  the value of that single input element is passed in the component. In my approach I would've just returned an extra attribute in createItem().  Could you maybe elaborate on that?